# Django unable to open sqlite on SOME queries only?

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I have had no troubles locally, but pushing a new project to an existing machine (one running plenty of other django apps without trouble) gave this:

```
OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

What is more perplexing is:

- The sqlite file is read-write for all
- This error only happens on *some* queries! Other's are fine.
- In a fresh db after running syncdb, my views work, but `/admin/` triggers this.
- If I loaddata for some of my apps from data dumped from my local machine, some of the apps trigger this in my views, and others do not.
- I can find no correlation between any of the things that seem to trigger this.

Why would it fail to open the database, aside from permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Write access on the directory. I thought i checked that first :-/